# Rails make record available to application view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I've got a module that lists `events` (`event_box`) and I want to define it as part of my `application.html.erb`:

```
<div id="left_sidebar">
    <%= render 'shared/user_box' %>
    <%= render 'shared/event_box' %>
    <%= render 'shared/server_info_box' %>
</div>
```

However, the `event_box` uses `@events`, which so far needs to be passed to it:

```
def home
    @events = Event.all
end
```

If it's going to be in the application layout, how do I pass `@events` to it without defining `@events` in every view in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a method in `ApplicationController` which fetches all the events.
Use this method as a `before_filter` in `ApplicationController`. Filters called in `ApplicationController` will apply to all the controllers inheriting from it.

`application_controller.rb`:

```
before_filter :fetch_events

def fetch_events
  @events = Event.all
  # @events = Event.where({}) can be used to lazy load the events
end
```

Since this is going to be executed before every action, consider using [Fragment caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) for that particular portion of the view.

Comment: thanks! worked great, thanks for the link to fragment caching.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code also in shared/event_box partial. It will work.

```
<% @events = Event.all %>
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <p><%= event.column_name %></p>
<% end %>
```